# Why does Cookie Session keep dying

Tags: android, http

I read several topis on this site how to keep session alive and itried to follow advises, but my client continiously loosing connection with server.
Comunication with erver fulfill JSONParser class, JSONParser gets HttpClient from UILApplication , which set and restore cookies if internet conection was droped. Unfortunatlythis does not works. Help me please to solve this problem.

UILApplication

```
public class UILApplication extends Application {
private static Object mLock = new Object();
    private static CookieStore mCookie = null;
public static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientFactory
                .getThreadSafeClient();
        synchronized (mLock) {
            if (mCookie == null) {
                mCookie = httpClient.getCookieStore();
            } else {
                httpClient.setCookieStore(mCookie);
            }

        }
        List<Cookie> cookies = mCookie.getCookies();
        if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d("COOK", "none");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                Log.d("COOK", "- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
        return httpClient;
    }
```

HttpClientFactory

```
public class HttpClientFactory {
    private static DefaultHttpClient client=null;
//  private static CookieStore mCookie = null;


    public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (i == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!i.isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!i.isAvailable()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public synchronized static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {

        if (client != null) {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIEN", "REUSE");

            // return client;
        } else {
            Log.d("HTTPCLIEN", "new");
            client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();

            HttpParams params = client.getParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
            HttpProtocolParams.setHttpElementCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);


            // return client;
        }
//      synchronized (mLock) {

        return client;
    }

    public synchronized static DefaultHttpClient killSession() {

        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();

        HttpParams params = client.getParams();
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
                mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);
//      
        return client;

    }
}
```

JSONParser

```
public class JSONParser {
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

        if (isOnline()) {
            try {

                String u = url;
                u = u + "?";

                httpClient = UILApplication.getHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
                for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
                    u = u + params.get(i).getName() + "="
                            + params.get(i).getValue() + "&";
                }
                Log.d("your url is", u);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                List<Cookie> cookies = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
                UILApplication.setCoockies(((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCookieStore());
                if (cookies.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("None");
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {

                        System.out.println("- " + cookies.get(i).toString());
                    }
                }
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.d("data is sent", "true");

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;

            }
            Log.d("wait", "true");
            try {

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
                if (json.contains("error:2")) {
                    return null;
                }
                Log.d("JSON", json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                return null;
            }
            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                return null;
            }
            // dialog.dismissDialog();
            // pd.dismiss();
            return jObj;
        }
        // pd.dismiss();
        // dialog.dismissDialog();

//      error();
        return null;

    }
}
```

**EDIT:** It looks like mCookie is erised by GC after some time, but why this heppens if it is a static field of a application class?

Comment: maybe the cookie has a timeout too short. If you're in chrome CTRL+SHIFT+I -> Resources (tab) -> Cookies and check the timeout of the cookie. maybe it is not your problem.

Comment: "Static variables cannot be elected for garbage collection while the class is loaded. They can be collected when the respective class loader (that was responsible for loading this class) is itself collected for garbage."

Comment: It looks like mCookie is erised by GC after some time, but why this heppens if it is a static field of a application class? "Are you sayving it using savedInstance ??"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `HttpURLConnection` for that, which is [recommended](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html).

You can then enable VM-wide cookie management like this:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
```

Cookies are then stored in memory only, but you can implement your own `CookieStore` if you want.

You can read more on cookies and `HttpURLConnection` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the cookie you get back from the server is a [session cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_cookie) which, keeping it simple, means that when you stop the application and run it again the cookie is discarded.

I would suggest to set on the server side a [Max-Age or an Expire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Expires_and_Max-Age) for the cookie. This should solve the problem.

Another way to debug this kind of issues is to print out the HTTP Headers you get back from the server. There could be in fact a bug which does not set correctly the cookie expiration or Max-Age.

Another really important thing is to set the [Secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly) attribute of the cookie if you are using it to authenticate the HTTP clients/requests otherwise your cookie will be sent every and each time you execute an HTTP request to the domain specified in the cookie, even though the request is about a download of an image for the very same domain. In this way if an attacker sniffs the network traffic can hijack the user session.